# MySQL 5.7.12 Different query result before and after TABLE OPTIMIZE

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7

Working with Amazon Aurora MySQL 5.7.12. And got strange issue.

Have next query

```
   SELECT d.BucketDate,
      SUM(d.Value),
      d.Key,
      d.Code,
      d.PlC
FROM MonthlyTable d
JOIN (SELECT #getting list of all available Key with last available BucketDate
             d1.Key, MAX(d1.BucketDate) AS BucketDT
        FROM MonthlyTable d1
        JOIN PCTemp AS pc ON d1.SnapshotDate = 'SOME SNAPSHOT DATE' and pc.PC = d1.PC
        JOIN PlCTemp AS p ON d1.SnapshotDate = 'SOME SNAPSHOT DATE' and p.PlC = d1.PlC
       WHERE d1.SnapshotDate = 'SOME SNAPSHOT DATE' 
         AND d1.param1 = 1
         AND d1.param2 IN (1 , 3)
       GROUP BY d1.Key) dd ON d.SnapshotDate = 'SOME SNAPSHOT DATE' and d.Key = dd.Key
WHERE d.SnapshotDate = 'SOME SNAPSHOT DATE'
        AND d.param1 = 1
        AND d.param2 IN (3 , 1)
        AND (d.BucketDate = dd.BucketDT OR d.BucketDate BETWEEN 'START DATE' AND 'END DATE')
GROUP BY d.Key , d.BucketDate;
```

The table is getting 6-8 millions of new records each day by SnapshotDate and partitioned by key on the SnapshotDate column.

Yesterday that query failed to return a result.
But:

1 - it started returning the correct result once I've changed `d.param2 IN (3 , 1)` to `d.param2 IN (1 , 3)`

2 - it started returning the correct result once I've forced the optimal index without query rewrite.

3 - it started returning the correct result after `OPTIMIZE TABLE MonthlyTable`

Any ideas on what was that?
How to prevent that happening again?

Comment: Did you do these with given order? For my opinion  `IN(3,1) AND IN(1,3)` does not matter and anything to do with your problem. `OPTIMIZE TABLE ` on the other hand could help table to return data.

Comment: I was surprised that changing the order in IN CLAUSE brought the result to me.
But anyway - as far as OPTIMIZE TABLE helped team is considering to add that optimization into some scheduled job. Is there are any other options?